# Netlify build fail with Gatsby site. Images

Tags: gatsby, netlify

I'm having an issue with deploying my site on Netlify. On the Netlify environment, I am getting a:

`3:30:14 PM: failed Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles - 37.321s 3:30:14 PM: error Generating JavaScript bundles failed 3:30:14 PM: Can't resolve '../../../images/inside-shop-dark.jpg' in '/opt/build/repo/src/pages/style/Index' 3:30:14 PM: If you're trying to use a package make sure that '../../../images/inside-shop-dark.jpg' is installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is correct.`

For a few images but the paths are correct and everything works locally and it builds locally no problem but I can't seem to get a successful build with Netlify.

Comment: Are you using Gatsby Image or just an img tag? Are you hardcoding your image paths or are you pulling them in from, say, frontmatter?

Answer (score 0):

It was just a casing issues with my files and github not recognizing the file name changes. everything works now thank you!